# Can't display a texture loaded asynchronously

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, grand-central-dispatch

In my game i have to change background of the scene during gameplay time. When i set new texture for the background the game slows down for a moment. In order to escape this i'm trying to preload a texture asynchronously and then show it on main thread. This is how i do that:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"res/src/level_%i/background.png", [GameLevel sharedGameLevel].currentLevelIndex + 1];
__block CCTexture2D *texture;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSLog(@"FILENAME %@", filename);
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:filename];
    NSLog(@"%@", [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache]);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:filename];

        [spareBackground setTexture:texture];

        [dayBackground runAction:[CCSequence actions:fadeOut,[CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node)
        {
            NSLog(@" TEXTURE %@", texture);
            [dayBackground setTexture:texture];
            CCFadeIn *fadeIn = [[[CCFadeIn alloc] initWithDuration:5] autorelease];
            [dayBackground runAction:fadeIn];
        }], nil]];      

    });
});
```

but instead of background i always receive a blank screen despite the texture has been successfully loaded, it's not `nil`. This code works just fine if the texture is loaded on the main thread without using gcd. What am i missing?

Comment: are all of your NSLogs up to the last one showing expected results?

Comment: and what about `sparebackground` vs. `dayBackground`? what are you trying to do? are both assignment producing a black texture?

Comment: @sergio all NSLogs showing what i expect to see. spareBackground just lies underneath dayBackground. yes, the both are blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspect is that `CCTextureCache` is not thread-safe (and being a shared object it would need to be thread safe in order to be safely called from another thread).

Cocos2d, on the other hand already provides mechanism to load a texture asynchronously, so you might use them instead. This should be the signature:

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImageAsync:filename target:self selector:@selector(textureLoaded:)];
```

Comment: @Andrey Chernukha: well, every task you run on the same CPU as the main thread's will slow the main thread down. If you look at `addImageAsync` implementation you will see that it simply loads the image in a separate thread (but it does it in a thread-safe way). there is no reason to believe that creating a CGD thread would be that much different (apart from the cost of handling the thread-safeness).

Comment: you have to use addImageAsync, no way around it

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to trade 'space' for 'time' , ie your game's memory footprint is reasonable, preload both textures at the start of the scene, and during game play, just flip the texture's visibility.

Also, i found that loading pvr textures instead of png's will run considerably faster (ie consume less cpu i guess). You could try that as a first attempt - hoping that the 'pause' would be acceptable from a user experience standpoint.

ps. any comment i make on performance are based on actual measurements and tests on real devices. The simulator is useless. Make certain this 'pause' is present on devices before spending any effort on optimizing.